# how to merge data while loading them into hive?

Tags: hadoop, hive

I'm tring to use hive to analysis our log, and I have a question.

Assume we have some data like this:
A 1
A 1
A 1
B 1
C 1
B 1
How can I make it like this in hive table(order is not important, I just want to merge them) ?
A 1
B 1
C 1

without pre-process it with awk/sed or something like that?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

**Step 1:** Create a Hive table for input data set . 
create table if not exists table1 (fld1 string, fld2    string ) ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t';
(i assumed field seprator is \t, you can replace it with actual separator)

**Step 2 :** Run below to get the merge data you are looking for

create table table2 as select fld1,fld2  from table1 group by fld1,fld2 ;

I tried this for below input set

hive (default)> select * from table1;
OK

A   1

A   1

A   1

B   1

C   1

B   1

create table table4 as select fld1,fld2  from table1 group by fld1,fld2 ;

hive (default)> select * from table4;
OK

A   1

B   1

C   1

You can use external table as well , but for simplicity I have used managed table here.

Comment: Or you can just do: "Select distinct fld1, fld2 from table1". Same output, but it looks a bit cleaner (well, at least for me)

Answer (score 2):

One idea.. you could create a table around the first file (called 'oldtable').

Then run something like this....
create table newtable select field1, max(field) from oldtable group by field1;

Not sure I have the syntax right, but the idea is to get unique values of the first field, and only one of the second.  Make sense?

Answer (score 0):

For merging the data, we can also use "UNION ALL" , it can also merge two different types of datatypes.

insert overwrite into table test1
(select x.* from t1 x )
UNION ALL
(select y.* from t2 y);

here we are merging two tables data (t1 and t2) into one single table test1.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to pre-process the data while it's being loaded without using an external program.  You could use a view if you'd like to keep the original data intact.

```
hive> SELECT * FROM table1;
OK
A       1
A       1
A       1
B       1
C       1
B       1
B       2 # Added to show it will group correctly with different values

hive> CREATE VIEW table2 (fld1, fld2) AS SELECT fld1, fld2 FROM table1 GROUP BY fld1, fld2;
hive> SELECT * FROM table2;
OK
A       1
B       1
B       2
C       1
```